# Loading data in Nested Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am creating UI similar to this one:

[image]

For this I did he following:
1. Took a parent recycler view
2. Defined two view types one for grid and one for vertical list and created two view holders.
3. Each view holder has a recycler view to which list and grid will be attached
4. Defined parent data model which is inherited by the models of list and grid.

The linear list contains around 2000 data. So when I am populating the child recycler view's adapter,  it loads all data 2000 data at once(which should not happen with recycler view), thus there is visible delay.
The data is fetched from server.
I am unable to figure out what is happening with the child recycler view.

Comment: Is cities shown in Grid are at top only ?

Comment: @Akshay Yes, they are on top. Basically these are in two arrays

Comment: Create a Header for Grid to your `RecyclerView` so you will not need to worry about the nested Scrolling.

Comment: You mean adding a header view to recyclerview?

Comment: Yes, Header of gridview

Comment: RecyclerView does not have addHeaderView like listview. The other way is to have two view holders, which is what I am doing now.

Comment: Yes, correct RecyclerView does not have direct way add Header

Answer (score -1):

Why not use one Recycler view to contain all of the things

Comment: I was thinking to do that. Unable to figure out, how to manage list and grid with single recycler view.

Comment: Use one RecyclerView, split your UI to different type, e.g : each grid row is one type, each other city is one type, so when you get data from server, you can split your data to the correspoding row type, this is my suggestion

Comment: That is what I explained in my question

Comment: sorry, Perhaps I understand it wrong，so your code only use one RecyclerView?